# How create pod with unrar under OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

I want to deploy my app, that using unrar, to OpenShift. But by default there is no unrar in /usr/bin directory in my deployment pod.

How to add functionality such as unrar or perl to OpenShift pod?

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your deployment pod are dictated by the container image that it is deploying.

You can build your own container image containing any tools you like using the buildah, podman, or docker CLI tools. There are many resources online detailing how this is done.

Comment: Can you provide me a simple examle of this?